# Has anyone tried moving a php Azure App Service to IIS?

Tags: php, azure, hosting

I'm not really an expert with php. But I've got an Azure app service which is built using Laravel php and Sql database. All these currently sittig on Azure... 
I need to move this Azure app service to IIS. Has any one out there done this before???

Comment: have you tried googling a guide for your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can leverage Git or FTP to download your whole Laravel application to local, then you move your application to your IIS server.

1. Log in to the Azure Portal.
2. In your App Service app's blade, click **Settings** > **Deployment source**. Click Choose source, then click **Local Git Repository**, and then click OK.
   [image]
3. If this is your first time setting up a repository in Azure, you need to create login credentials for it. You will use them to log into the Azure repository and push changes from your local Git repository. From your app's blade, click **Settings** > **Deployment credentials**, then configure your deployment username and password. When you're done, click **Save**.
   [image]
4. Then you can find the Git, FTP url in the Overview **Essentials**
   tab
   [image]

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I tried that and I was able to see the files through the ftp in file explorer. But I was unable to copy all contents to my local. It would just say Calculating for a very long time and not actually copy contents...

Comment: Oh yes finally, I let the copy for about 1 hr by mistake and it started copying to my local...